# Not able to create a database object and access it in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am writing a demo sms application that can send and receive messages and show conversations .For that I had written a class that handled the complete database part .But problem is I am unable to create database object inside the broadcast receiver class that is used to receive the sms.`package com.example.demosmsapp;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ID="_id";
    static final String KEY_NUM="number";
        static final String KEY_TEXT="contents";
        static final String KEY_FLAG="flag";

        static final String DATABASE_NAME="smsapp";
        static final String DATABASE_TABLE="sms";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE="create table sms(_id integer primary key auto increment, number text not null,contents text not null,flag text not null );";
    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context=ctx;
        DBHelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);

    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try{
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            }catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion)
        {
            //Log.w(TAG,"upgrading from version:"+oldVersion+"to"+newVersion);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sms");
        }
    }
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    public long insertSms(String number,String contents,String flag)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues=new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NUM,number);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TEXT,contents);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FLAG,flag);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,initialValues);

    }
    public Cursor getAllSms()
    {
        return db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{KEY_NUM},null,null,KEY_NUM,null,null,null);
    }
    public Cursor getConv(String num)
    { 

        Cursor mCursor= db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{KEY_TEXT,KEY_FLAG,KEY_NUM},KEY_NUM + "=" +num ,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(mCursor !=null){
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public boolean deleteConv(String del)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "number="+del, null)>0;
    }

}
```

`
the above is my database implementation and the below is my sms receiver implemntation

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
            //db.open();
              .....
              .....
           }
```

}

When i am trying to write the commentet out portion in the second code it shows the error that "the constructor DBAdapter(SMSBroadcastReceiver) is undefined".But using the same statemnt i was able to do all actions in my main activity.
Why is it and how to solve it

Comment: you need to pass the context.

Comment: and can i know how to do it..because i tried doing it using this statement but it doesn't work  @njzk2

Comment: `DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);` in onReceive...